# How do I enable DPRP for my paypal business account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm working in the paypal sandbox trying to setup a subscription/billing agreement with a credit card and am seeing an error that reads `message: 'DPRP is disabled for this merchant.'`. How can I enable DPRP in the sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

For sandbox accounts, you could file a ticket with the PayPal MTS team to have them enable it for you.

https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask

Jeremy